# Jquery UI calendar control disable specific dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to disable first saturday of every month + I want to disable all sundays
I have tried below code which will only disable every sundays.How can I disable first saturday of every month ??
Below is the code I have tried : 
$(function () {

```
        $("#txtDate").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: noSunday
        });
        function noSunday(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [(day > 0), ''];
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done a pretty good work on disabling the Sunday as mentioned in your question.
As `(day > 0)` will enable date except for the Sunday's. Now, for adding the restriction for the first Monday of the month you can use,

```
var day = date.getDay();
day.getDate(); //Returns the numbering of date. e.g Jan 1 will return 1 , Jan 2 will return 2 and so on.
```

So if you want to check for First Monday you need to do,

```
!(day==6 && date.getDate() <= 7)
//Day==6 denotes Saturday
```

So, The complete code will look like,

```
function disableDate(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      return [ (day!=0 && !(day==6 && date.getDate() <= 7)), ''];
 }
```

#### See the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/381/).

Comment: I want all Saturday's to be disabled,not .MONDAYS. Also I want to show first saturday,rest of saturday should get disabled.

Comment: So, What seems to be the problem just restructured the equation above to get the desired result.

Comment: Yes i misunderstood the problem and disabled the Monday instead.  But it conflict with your comment above : `How can I disable first saturday of every month ??`